# Should C# answers include usings or be fully qualified?

Tags: discussion, answers

I like to answer in `C#` pretty much exclusively so far. Whenever I answer I either include the `using` statements required or fully qualify anything else.

I often see a lot of `C#` answers that do not do this and people are always unsure in the comments as to whether or not they should include them.

As I have not found a question asking this and relating to `C#`:

Should C# answers include the using statements/be fully qualified or is not doing this okay?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8287/48934).

Comment: @LeakyNun Would it be a good idea to point people to that other post when commenting that they are required? Oh and thanks for finding the duplicate looks like my searching is not so top notch